# assembler for arm assembly on beagleboard ubuntu

Tags: gcc, ubuntu, assembly, arm

Hi I have a beagleboard revC4 running ubuntu, I was wondering if it is possible to compile arm assembly such as that used in Kiel uVision IDE:

```
      AREA  RESET, CODE, READONLY 
      ENTRY
      ADR   r1, TEXT
LOOP  LDRB  r0, [r1], #1
      CMP   r0, #0
      BNE   LOOP
      B     .
TEXT = "Hello World!", &0a, &0d, 0
      END
```

for some reason any examples I find use gcc and the ASM code is quite different
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look into the tools provided by ARM:

```
http://www.arm.com/products/tools/software-tools/index.php
```

It's really an assembler you're looking for, not a compiler...  The easiest solution for you may be to lerarn the [GNU assembler syntax](http://microcross.com/GNU-ARM-Assy-Quick-Ref.pdf) (which shouldn't be that different).